# Where can I find the list of shortcuts for Jupyter Notebook in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, vscode-keybinding

I am using the latest `v1.41.1` VSCode version and launching a jupyter notebook within it.

I cannot seem to find the standard jupyter notebook keyboard shortcut menu to customize, e.g., the hotkey for cutting or creating a cell.

I have looked under `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts` but I only see the shortcuts to run a cell or all cells.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use VS Code's keybindings UI editor to browse existing keybindings (the `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts` command) (which you already know).

You can also find the "source code" (source configuration?) for the contributed commands and default keybindings in the Juptyer extensions in their package.json files in the `"contributes"` > `"keyBindings"` and `"contributes"` > `"keyBindings"` respectively:

- [`microsoft/vscode-jupyter/package.json`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/blob/main/package.json) (for the "top-level" extension pack)

  - [`microsoft/vscode-jupyter-keymap/package.json`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter-keymap/blob/main/package.json)
  - [`microsoft/vscode-notebook-renderers/package.json`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-notebook-renderers/blob/main/package.json)
  - [`microsoft/vscode-jupyter-slideshow/package.json`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter-slideshow/blob/main/package.json)
  - [`microsoft/vscode-jupyter-cell-tags/package.json`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter-cell-tags/blob/main/package.json)

(I'd link to specific line numbers, but those are subject to change for the latest commit, and I don't want to link to a specific commit and have to keep updating this post. Better for you to just `ctrl+f` in whatever tool you choose to browse the source code with)

You might also be interested in looking at the `"contributes"` > `"configuration"` field (the list of contributed setting IDs).